# Facebook instant game login with JS SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-instant-games

I am trying to upload my game made with React to Facebook Instant games. I have facebook login implemented with Facebook JS SDK. But facebook instant game runs inside a sandboxed iframe which blocks any popups and I cannot run FB.login(). In instant games [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login/) it says that FB.login should work and it should open a popup in 'async' mode. But it doesn't. Login popup gets blocked and I get the following error:

Blocked opening ... in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

Comment: You are looking at the docs for Games on Facebook there, what used to be called Canvas. That's not the same thing as Instant Games. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/social-and-retention/features/login-for-gaming

Comment: @CBroe, your link leads to the "Login for Gaming" page. As I understand it is different from "Instant games". Instant games are HTML5 games that are hosted on facebook (that's what i need). "Login for Gaming" is for games made with Unity/IOS/Android games that are not hosted on facebook.

Comment: You can not use normal login via the FB JS SDK for instant games. You need to use the instant games SDK then, and what functionality it provides to get player info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/sdk/fbinstant6.3

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. Now I get it ) Can you post your answer in the "answers" section so I can mark it as a correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the wrong documentation, which leads to Legacy Web games.
You need to refer to the [Facebook Instant Game SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/sdk/fbinstant7.0) to get the user information inside a FB Instant Game. Most importantly FB Instant games don't allow to use of the Facebook Graph API within the FB Instant Game. Although the Graph API offers more capabilities like getting the [user gender](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/user_gender/), the Facebook Instant Game SDK only exposes a limited number of data for developers. The Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK is an OAuth login that cannot be used inside a FB Instant Game.

FYI: Facebook Instant GAme SDK v7.0 doesn't provide all the user information about the user. It only provides the following data

- Display Name

  ```
   var playerName = FBInstant.player.getName()
  ```
- Profile Picture

  ```
  var playerImage = new Image();
  playerImage.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  playerImage.src = FBInstant.player.getPhoto();
  ```

You can only use the above information in your FB instant games.